# How to store images in 2D array?

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

I want to store drawable images in a 2D array

```
ImageView iv1[][] = new ImageView[2][20];
    int mylist[][]={{R.drawable.step_000,R.drawable.step_001,R.drawable.step_002,R.drawable.step_003,R.drawable.step_004,
        R.drawable.step_005,R.drawable.step_006,R.drawable.step_007,R.drawable.step_008,R.drawable.step_009,R.drawable.step_010,
        R.drawable.step_011,R.drawable.step_012,R.drawable.step_013,R.drawable.step_014,R.drawable.step_015,R.drawable.step_016,
        R.drawable.step_017,R.drawable.step_018,R.drawable.step_019}, 

        {R.drawable.step_100,R.drawable.step_101,R.drawable.step_102,R.drawable.step_103,R.drawable.step_104,
        R.drawable.step_105,R.drawable.step_106,R.drawable.step_107,R.drawable.step_108,R.drawable.step_109,R.drawable.step_110,
        R.drawable.step_111,R.drawable.step_112,R.drawable.step_113,R.drawable.step_114,R.drawable.step_115,R.drawable.step_116,
        R.drawable.step_117,R.drawable.step_118,R.drawable.step_119}};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data);
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.left);
    iv3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.right);
    iv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    String value=bundle.getString("key");
    int step = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("steps");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+step,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    int a;
    a=step;
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<a; j++)
        iv1[i][j] = (ImageView)findViewById(mylist[i][j]);
    }


    if(value.contentEquals("cristiano"))
    {
    iv.setImageResource(mylist[i][j]);
    }
```

Comment: my 20 images are not running..only a single image is working..

Comment: ArrayIndexOutBoundException in the best case

Comment: ImageView iv1[][] = new ImageView[2][20]; for(int i=0;i<20;i++) iv1[i][j] = ... There should be an error happening.

Comment: @user3432085 hows your `if(value.contentEquals("cristiano"))
    {
    iv.setImageResource(mylist[i][j]);
    }` not showing any error ? Have you declared `i` and `j` globally ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are setting everything in the iv1 ImageView array correctly, using the two for loops.  The problem is that you are setting one ImageView on the screen to the entire array, so it is only going to show one. You should try doing a GridLayout of multiple ImageViews and then setting each of those one by one.  I know it would be convenient to do it this way, but I don't think there is a way to make it work like that.  In addition, I would think that `iv.setImageResource(mylist[i][j]);` would give you trouble as it is outside the loop and does not know what `i` or `j` are.